# AWS / how can i get a database records running on ec2 instance and send them to kinesis?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-kinesis

I have a postgres database running on an ec2 instance , I want to move data (from postgres database) to kinesis stream to implement a real time dashboard ? It is possible ?
and thanks

Comment: You would need to write some code that queries the database and then uses the AWS SDK to send data to Kinesis. That code would need to run somewhere that it can access both the database and Kinesis. Kinesis can be accessed via the Internet or a VPC Endpoint for Kinesis.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Kinesis stream and Kinesis Firehose to pull data from Postgres DB and push it to Amazon S3 bucket which can be further connected with Amazon [QuickSight](https://aws.amazon.com/quicksight/) for creating visualization.

Check out this [blog post](https://blog.dbi-services.com/sending-postgresql-data-to-aws-s3-by-using-aws-kinesis-data-streams/) for similar solution.